# Is there any limit on the number of request to be made to Python gtts module?

Tags: python

I am doing my college project which uses python gtts and I have used the gTTS module(I have used the module to convert the text to speech using gtts) but after few days I am getting the error of something like Max retries exceeded with the URL:

The actual error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 135, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 66, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):   File "C:\Python\lib\socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 782, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 215, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 144, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000132FB57A438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 609, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 271, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000132FB57A438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    tts.save('Hello.mp3')   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 94, in save
    self.write_to_fp(f)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 107, in write_to_fp
    'tk' : self.token.calculate_token(part)}   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py", line 28, in calculate_token
    seed = self._get_token_key()   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py", line 58, in
_get_token_key
    response = requests.get("https://translate.google.com/")   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 423, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000132FB57A438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Now I want to know the possible cause and any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what information you've posted, this has nothing to do with limits on the gtts module.

You're getting "max retries exceeded" from your client, which is trying to submit a request somewhere, failing, and retrying a few times before giving up.  Based on the error you pasted, your error is `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`.  What that means is that you're no longer able to find the information to connect to the host that you've been connecting to.  Either you've changed your code's `host` or `port`, or for some reason, you can longer resolve the address.

Looking into getaddrinfo, I don't see it returning an error code of 11001, and the command-line utility `perror` doesn't recognize that error code, either.

If you didn't change the hostname or port, my hunch would be that you're no longer able to resolve the hostname.  You can try using `nslookup` to see if you can resolve the name.  If you can, try running your code using the given IP's numeric form instead of using the domain name.  If nslookup couldn't find the host, then the host is no longer resolvable.  Either your school removed that site from its name server, or the site no longer exists.